# Getting an error when running apt update: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: 18.04, python, python3

When I run `apt update` on a **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS**, which is a server my company use for hosting Netbox, I get the following issue:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
```

I get a similar issue when I run `neofetch`:

```
$ neofetch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

A colleague of mine told me to run these and try again, but I got the same issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove command-not-found
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install command-not-found
```

Then I went to check how many python version are installed on this server, and I count 4:

```
$ ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
3544 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3628904 Nov 28 18:51 /usr/bin/python2.7
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Jan 10 08:10 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1018 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsondiff
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3661 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpatch
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1342 May  1  2016 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpointer
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     398 Nov 15  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema
5356 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5481816 Dec  7 01:11 /usr/bin/python3.10
4424 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Nov 25 14:10 /usr/bin/python3.6
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Nov 25 14:10 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
4424 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Nov 25 14:10 /usr/bin/python3.6m
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Nov 25 14:10 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
```

Running `python3 --version` it returns `Python 3.10.9`

Does anyone have a clue how can I resolve this issue without having to migrate the hosted app? That would be a nightmare :(

EDIT:

I moved to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` looked for `apt_pkg` via `ls -la | grep "apt_pkg.cpython"` and found the file `apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, I renamed the file to `apt_pkg.so` and now I could run `apt update` with a new error message:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for admin-federico-dostuni:
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [83.3 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease
Fetched 172 kB in 1s (176 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.1.15) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 78, in <module>
    class TagSectionWrapper(collections.Mapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because of the file `/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader`, its first line contains this:

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

---

from ahead info, your python is `Python 3.10.9`,

and apt_pkg is `apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, which means it only match the python3.6, you may should do:

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python3`

`sudo ln -f /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`

make sure the `python3 --version` is `python3.6.x`

run update command for a test,

`sudo apt update`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04.

I kept receiving warnings and error prompts when I tried to do `apt update`, detail goes like

`Fetched 16.8 kB in 1s (14.2 kB/s)    sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found Reading package lists... Done W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2 W: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi' E: Sub-process returned an error code`

It turned out to be the `/usr/bin/python3` was linked to a void address. When I checked with `ls -ls /usr/bin/python*`, there is a red line indicating which is not available.

What I did find useful is reset this link with `ln -s /usr/bin/pythonVERSIONAVAILABLE /usr/bin/python3`.

Solved.